# Dijkstra Algorithm Python - KeyError: 'C'

Tags: python, cs50, dijkstra

my Dijkstra code returns the right solution but there is still an error when I run a unit test. I don't get why. I really would appreciate some help :)
Here is my Dijkstra. The first methods can be ignored.

```
class Graph(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def add_vertex(self, key):
        self[key] = []

    def add_edge(self, origin, target, weight):
        # add vertices
        if origin not in self:
            self.add_vertex(origin)
        if target not in self:
            self.add_vertex(target)

        # add edges
        self[origin].append((target, weight))
        self[target].append((origin, weight))

        # sort list of tupels
        self[origin].sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
        self[target].sort(key=lambda item: item[1])

    def dfs(self, start, vertex_list=[]):
        if start not in vertex_list:
            vertex_list.append(start)
            if start not in self:
                return vertex_list
            for neighbour in self[start]:
                vertex_list = self.dfs(neighbour[0], vertex_list)
        return vertex_list

    def bfs(self, start):
        queue = []
        visited = []
        vertex_list = []
        # add root to queue
        queue.append(start)
        visited.append(start)
        while queue != []:
            # save element and remove from queue
            ele = queue[0]
            vertex_list.append(ele)
            queue.pop(0)
            # add neighbours
            for neighbour in self[ele]:
                neighbour = neighbour[0]
                if neighbour not in visited:
                    queue.append(neighbour)
                    visited.append(neighbour)

        print(vertex_list)
        return vertex_list

    def dijkstra(self, start, end):
        shortest_distance = {}
        track_predecessor = {}
        # copy of dict to iterate through the nodes
        unseen_nodes = self
        infinity = 9999
        # trace back the path
        track_path = []

        # set weights to 9999 but not the start value
        for i in unseen_nodes:
            shortest_distance[i] = infinity
        shortest_distance[start] = 0

        # iterate until all nodes were visited
        while unseen_nodes:
            min_distance_node = None

            # if first iteration set min_distance_node to first note
            for i in unseen_nodes:
                if min_distance_node is None:
                    min_distance_node = i

                # update min_distance_node if value is smaller
                elif shortest_distance[i] < shortest_distance[min_distance_node]:
                    min_distance_node = i

            # print("Min: ", min_distance_node)

            # get values of min_distance_node
            path_options = self.get(min_distance_node)

            for child_node, weight in path_options:

                if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
                    shortest_distance[child_node] = weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node]

                    track_predecessor[child_node] = min_distance_node

            unseen_nodes.pop(min_distance_node)

        current_node = end

        while current_node != start:
            try:
                track_path.insert(0, current_node)
                current_node = track_predecessor[current_node]
            except KeyError:
                print('Path not reachable')
                break
        track_path.insert(0, start)

        if shortest_distance[end] != infinity:
            print('Shortest distance is ' + str(shortest_distance[end]))
            print('And the path is ' + str(track_path))
        result = (shortest_distance[end], track_path)
        return result
```

And here is the given main method main.py. I think the only relevant lines here are the last three ones

```
import sys
import graphviz
from network import Graph
import os

def print_graph(g):
    graph = graphviz.Graph(format='png', strict=True, filename='network')
    for n in g.keys():
        graph.node(n, n)

    for n in g.keys():
        for t, w in g[n]:
            graph.edge(n, t, label=str(w))
    graph.render()
    os.remove('network')

g = Graph()
Edges = [('yahoo.com', 'google.com', 3), ('yahoo.com', 'facebook.com', 2), ('yahoo.com', 'twitter.com', 2), ('google.com', 'facebook.com', 5), ('google.com', 'twitter.com', 3), \
        ('google.com', 'instagram.com', 1), ('google.com', 'reddit.com', 5), ('LordVoldemodem', 'google.com', 1), ('reddit.com', 'instagram.com', 1), ('instagram.com', 'twitter.com', 1), \
        ('twitter.com', 'facebook.com', 1), ('DesktopD', 'DesktopC', 3), ('DesktopD', 'Mobile1', 1), ('Mobile1', 'DesktopC', 2), ('DesktopC', 'Modem', 1)]

for edge in Edges:
    a, b, c = edge
    g.add_edge(a, b, c)
print(g)
print(g.dfs('yahoo.com'))
print(g.bfs('twitter.com'))
a, b = g.dijkstra('yahoo.com', 'reddit.com')
print('Path: ' + str(b))
#print(g.bfs('Mobile1'))
```

My error in the console:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Further information:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an error internal to your checker tool, so it's hard to say what the problem is or what "C" refers to

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).